# Mixing matrix for $\pi ,\eta ,\eta '$ mesons

Tags: particle-physics

My first question on this site concerned experimental evidence about the ratio of $U\bar{U}$ to $D\bar{D}$ content of the neutral pion, or in other words, its isospin purity.  But what does theory say?  I have a vision of a mass matrix with unequal $Q\bar{Q}$ masses (squared) on the diagonal and roughly equal mixing elements everywhere.  Its eigenvalues would represent observed meson masses (squared).

‘t Hooft tried to explain the mechanism that gives the $\eta '$ mass non-perturbatively, via instantons and the triangle anomaly, but the experimental value of the theta parameter is consistent with zero.  Is his explanation still viable?

Isn’t there a significant perturbative contribution from an intermediate state of two (or more) gluons?  Imagine two triangle diagrams joined back-to-back by gluon propagators.  My intuition says the mixing element should scale like ${{p}^{2}}{{g}^{4}}(p)\log (?)$, where $p$ is the momentum that flows through, but the algebra says there’s a quadratic divergence.  Huh?  How should one deal with the naughty gluon loop: $\left\langle  0 \right|{{g}^{4}}\int{{{d}^{4}}x}\ \exp (ipx)\ {{\varepsilon }^{....}}{{F}_{..}}{{F}_{..}}(x)\ {{\varepsilon }^{....}}{{F}_{..}}{{F}_{..}}(0)\left| 0 \right\rangle $?

The coupling of mesons to the triangle diagram raises a further question.  The accepted calculation of the neutral pion’s decay rate uses ${{f}_{\pi }}^{-1}$ and gets the right answer, but what about heavier $Q\bar{Q}$ states?

If the lightest neutral meson were “overweight” in the lightest quarks, the proportion would affect the neutral pion’s decay rate.  A hypothetical $U\bar{U}$ meson should decay to two photons 3.55 times faster than an ideal $(U\bar{U}-D\bar{D})/\sqrt{2}$ meson of similar mass.

Comment: Since nobody has ventured to answer my question, I’ll double-dare myself, so here’s my wag at the second question:  The calculation of pion decay via the triangle anomaly is only as good as PCAC, i.e., approximate.  It’s not exactly right to equate the pion to a local current operator.  A realistic treatment with a non-local pion vertex would presumably find that ${{\varepsilon }^{....}}{{F}_{..}}{{F}_{..}}$ is not precisely local either, hence its momentum dependence would keep the gluon loop finite.  Does anybody agree?